# Changing CSS element on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know there is a simple way to do this but I can't seem to find it.  I have a drop down box, which has a list.  Once you hover your mouse over any one of the items on the list, it's encircled by a border.  This is great.

What I want is for when a user selects an item from this list.  It will automatically change the background colour to #ddd.

If the user selects another item from the list, it will deselect the other item items background.

So, I have a class called 'hi'.

My CSS is like so:

```
#changer a{
    padding:3px;
    border: solid 1px #fff;    
}
#changer a.hi{
    background:#ddd;
}
#changer a:hover{
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I've added this script but it just selects the item from the list but it doesn't deselect the other one.  It just toggles the background colours.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hi");
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be mostly appreciated.

Cheers,

Jonny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function() {

    // remove existing "hi"s on other links
    $("a.hi").not(this).removeClass("hi");

    // toggle "hi" on this
    $(this).toggleClass("hi");
});
```

If you want the links to behave like mutually-exclusive checkboxes (can only select one, but can also deselect current) then use the above code, but if you want them to behave like a set of radio buttons (can only select one, but can't deselect current), use the following instead.

```
$("a").click(function() {

    // remove existing "hi"s on other links
    $("a.hi").not(this).removeClass("hi");

    // add "hi" to this
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hi'))
        $(this).addClass("hi");
});
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  Although, I'm going to be a bit awkward here and ask if this list was split into two, and they both had the same classes.  How can I differentiate the split?  So if I had the option to select 5 items from the list.  I could do this using the code above.  But what if there were two other items on the list, which would need to be selected or deselected in their own case?I hope that makes sesne.

Comment: That's not too difficult. As it's out of scope of the original question I won't append the solution to the answer, but you can check one possible way to do it at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/smWx3/)

Comment: Hi Goran, I can see how you're doing this.  But you've changed the class.  If you look at [this](http://my-wardrobe.com) website, you'll see what I'm trying to achieve. Take a look at the currency and language changer in the top right hand corner

Comment: Some form of class/markup modification will be needed to get them working. Do you mean having two seperate lists of links which allow you select a single item from each?

Comment: Correct yes.  This would be it

Comment: No worries, try this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/smWx3/1/).

Comment: Hi Goran, thanks for your help.  I know this thread is getting pretty long now.  When I add this to my script and select one of the links.  The page refreshes, but the selected item from the list doesn't look selected.  I don't know if this is something to do with cookies or what.  Here is a fiddle I did and how my menu looks. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnystudent/kmqx7/) Then if you have a look at the [site](http://my-wardrobe.com) I'm trying to mimic, you'll see my problem. Cheers Jonny

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about JS & Cookies to advise, but most likely you'll need some server-side implementation that isn't javascript to track and render the menu as well as any other elements on the page that are affected by the menu's state.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:active` on this write like this:

```
#changer a:active{
    background:#ddd;
}
```